# Node Text Positioning Not Working Properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I need to have two boxes with the size of the bigger one, including the "text" inside each of them a number of times (different for each of them).

When I write the following code it gives me the result shown below (the text appears outside the box and not in the desired number of repetitions).

Can anyone help?

Thanks

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\newbox\mybox
\def\mysaver{%
\pgfmathparse{\pgfpositionnodelatermaxx-\pgfpositionnodelaterminx}%
\xdef\nodeW{\pgfmathresult pt}%
\pgfmathparse{\pgfpositionnodelatermaxy-\pgfpositionnodelaterminy}%
\xdef\nodeH{\pgfmathresult pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}

{\pgfpositionnodelater{\mysaver}
% This node is clearly outside the grid
\node [inner sep=0] {Text};}

\node (a)
[draw,rounded corners=6pt,rectangle,inner sep=0.4cm]
{
    \tikz{
    \foreach \x in {0,\nodeW+0.2cm,\nodeW*2+0.2cm*2,\nodeW*3+0.2cm*3,\nodeW*4+0.2cm*4}
    \foreach \y in {0,\nodeH+0.2cm,\nodeH*2+0.2cm*2,\nodeH*3+0.2cm*3}
        \node [inner sep=0] at (\x,\y) {Text};
    \node [inner sep=0] at (\nodeW*2+0.2cm*2,\nodeH*4+0.2cm*4) {Text};
    }
};

\node (b) [right=0.4cm of a,inner sep=0] {Text Text};

{\pgfpositionnodelater{\mysaver}
% This node is clearly outside the grid
\node [inner sep=0] {Text};}

\node (c) [fit=(a),right=0.4cm of b,draw,rounded corners=6pt,rectangle,inner sep=0]
{
    \tikz{
        \foreach \x in {0,\nodeW+0.2cm}
        \foreach \y in {0,\nodeH+0.2cm,\nodeH*2+0.2cm*2}
            \node [inner sep=0] at (\x,\y) {Text};
    }
};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is a link to the figure since uploading it is not working with me: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e_bcgi96F45zsaeAd0kYY96fpe53mAR4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can upload images directly to your post, please do that, the method you used doesn't work.

Comment: Note that nesting `tikzpicture`s is in general a bad idea, and can cause problems, so it might be better to find a different approach.

Comment: add the picture and remove the initial `!` we will add it for you but google drive linking won't work. Right click the picture select copy image and then in the question click the image add button and directly paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that one should not nest Ti*k*Z pictures, and here is also no need for this.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc}

\newbox\mybox
\def\mysaver{%
\pgfmathparse{\pgfpositionnodelatermaxx-\pgfpositionnodelaterminx}%
\xdef\nodeW{\pgfmathresult pt}%
\pgfmathparse{\pgfpositionnodelatermaxy-\pgfpositionnodelaterminy}%
\xdef\nodeH{\pgfmathresult pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}

{\pgfpositionnodelater{\mysaver}
% This node is clearly outside the grid
\node [inner sep=0] {Text};}

\node (a)
[draw,rounded corners=6pt,rectangle,inner sep=0.4cm]
{
    \tikz{
    \foreach \x in {0,\nodeW+0.2cm,\nodeW*2+0.2cm*2,\nodeW*3+0.2cm*3,\nodeW*4+0.2cm*4}
    \foreach \y in {0,\nodeH+0.2cm,\nodeH*2+0.2cm*2,\nodeH*3+0.2cm*3}
        \node [inner sep=0] at (\x,\y) {Text};
    \node [inner sep=0] at (\nodeW*2+0.2cm*2,\nodeH*4+0.2cm*4) {Text};
    }
};

\node (b) [right=0.4cm of a,inner sep=0] {Text Text};

{\pgfpositionnodelater{\mysaver}
% This node is clearly outside the grid
\node [inner sep=0] {Text};}

\node (c) [fit=(a),right=0.4cm of b,draw,rounded corners=6pt,rectangle,inner sep=0]
{
};
        \foreach \x in {0,\nodeW+0.2cm}
        \foreach \y in {0,\nodeH+0.2cm,\nodeH*2+0.2cm*2}
            \node [inner sep=0] at ($(c.center)+(\x,\y)$) {Text};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you need to use `Tikz`. If not, you could use `tcolorbox` and build the result with an `equal height group`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
    notitle,
    equal height group=MyGroup,
    before=,
    after=\hfill,
    valign=center,
    #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}[width=.4\linewidth]
Text\\ Text Text Text Text\\
Text Text Text Text\\
Text Text Text Text\\
\end{mybox}
%
\begin{mybox}[blanker, width=15mm]
Text Text
\end{mybox}
%
\begin{mybox}[width=.3\linewidth]
Text Text\\
Text Text
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]